# How would evolution explain parastitic wasps?

Tags: evolution, parasitology, wasps

I read this article about wasps that can do "brain surgery" on cockroaches.
https://www.wired.com/2014/02/absurd-creature-of-the-week-jewel-wasp/

How does evolution create such a thing?

- The brain surgery along with many of the other steps in the reproduction process seems to be very precise.  Any error here or there could lead to a bad result
- Even if by happenstance the first wasp figured out a good way to do brain surgery, how would its offspring know to do the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In general we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, we expect you to look for similar questions on this site before posting — there are many including the one I've flagged. Thanks! 

Comment: I encourage you to check out some of the online resources available for learning more about evolution. For example, [this a useful introduction to evolutionary theory from UC Berkeley](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01).
You might also find a book like ["The Blind Watchmaker"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blind_Watchmaker) helpful for understanding how complex behaviors and structures arise through evolutionary processes.